# How to access solution for dual simplex solver?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, constraint-programming

I have an objective function with several hundreds of quadratic terms which I would like to minimize; in this case I try to minimize the absolute distance between several variables. So the structure of my problem looks like this (highly simplified):

```
Minimize
obj: [ a^2 - 2 a * b + b^2 ] / 2
Subject To
c1: a + b >= 10
c2: a <= 100
End
```

I use the Python API to solve the problem in the following way:

```
import cplex

cpx = cplex.Cplex()
cpx.read('quadratic_obj_so.lp')  
# use the dual simplex   
cpx.parameters.lpmethod.set(cpx.parameters.lpmethod.values.dual)
cpx.solve()
print cpx.solution.get_values()[0:15]
print cpx.solution.status[cpx.solution.get_status()]
print cpx.solution.get_objective_value()
```

And for the above example I then receive (showing only iterations 16-18):

```
Itn      Primal Obj        Dual Obj  Prim Inf Upper Inf  Dual Inf
  16   1.4492800e-19  -1.0579911e-07  3.81e-14  7.11e-15  5.17e-25
  17   9.0580247e-21  -2.6449779e-08  1.91e-14  3.55e-15  2.33e-25
  18   5.6612645e-22  -6.6124446e-09  5.45e-14  7.11e-15  6.46e-27

[73.11695794600045, 73.11695794603409]
optimal
0.0
```

so `a` and `b` are equal which makes sense since I try to minimize their distance and the constrains are clearly fulfilled.

However, my actual problem is far more complex and I receive:

```
Itn      Primal Obj        Dual Obj  Prim Inf Upper Inf  Dual Inf
92   1.4468496e+06   1.2138985e+06  1.80e+02  2.64e-12  5.17e-02
  93   1.4468523e+06   1.2138969e+06  2.23e+02  2.17e-12  1.08e-02
  94   1.4468541e+06   1.2138945e+06  2.93e+02  2.31e-12  5.62e-02
  *    1.4457132e+06   1.2138598e+06  7.75e+00  7.61e-09  2.76e-02

num_best
1445714.46525
```

I have now several questions regarding the output which are closely connected:

1) Clearly, it is not the objective value for the dual simplex printed. Why is that, since I set the solver to be the dual simplex?!

2) How do I now access the results for the dual simplex? As the objective value is smaller I would be more interested in these results.

3) Does the `num_best` status guarantee that all the constrains are met i.e. is the solution valid but just not guaranteed to be optimal?

4) `Primal Obj` and `Dual Obj` differ quite a lot. Is there any strategy to minimize their difference?

Comment: I don't think this log is from dual simplex but rather from the barrier method. Note also that solving QPs is not normally done with a Simplex LP method.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen: thanks for your comment! What would you recommend instead?

Comment: I would first look at some possible reformulations. Try to move as much as possible logic out of the objective into the linear constraints (e.g. (x+y)^2 can be written as z^2 with z=x+y). Also look at scaling. Try the Cplex option `numericalEmphasis`.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To the best of my knowledge, [get_objective_value](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/getobjval.html?cp=SSSA5P_12.6.3%2F2-8-0-0-12&lang=en) always returns the best primal bound (regardless of the lpmethod).
2. Information about the dual solution can be retrieved with [get_dual_values](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/cpxapi/getpi.html?cp=SSSA5P_12.6.3%2F2-8-0-0-14&lang=en).
3. The num_best solution status means that a solution is available, but there is no proof of optimality (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcallablelibrary/macros/CPX_STAT_NUM_BEST.html)).  This is probably the most important point with regards to the rest of the questions here.
4. You could try turning on the [numerical emphasis](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/NumericalEmphasis.html) parameter to see if that helps.  There are also various tolerances you can adjust (e.g., [optimality tolerance](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/EpOpt.html)).

Note that all of the links I've used above are for the C Callable Library (which the Python API calls internally) for CPLEX 12.6.3.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply (I upvoted it and accept later on)! Regarding point 3 just to make that sure: the returned solution is valid (none of the bounds is violated) but it cannot be proofed whether it is the optimal one. Is this correct? By now I think that it might be better to express the difference between the variables not as a `(x1 - x2)^2 + (x2-x3)^2 + ...` but as `abs(x1-x2) + abs(x2-x3) + ...`. Latter expression needs to be linearized, of course. Do you know any examples where the sum of absolute differences has been minimized?

Comment: No, with the num_best solution status, I don't think you can assume that the solution is valid.  If I understand correctly, you may find [this](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2012/07/modeling-absolute-values.html) blog on absolute values interesting.  In the object oriented API's (C++, Java, .NET) you can use the [abs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloModeler.html#abs(ilog.concert.IloIntExpr)) method.

Comment: Ok, thanks, this blog entry is indeed helpful. Did you have time to check point 1) ?

Comment: I asked around and did some testing with a callback and setting iteration limits.  I believe point 1) is correct and I've made the statement a bit stronger there.

Comment: The link to the `abs` method is broken. Are there any plans to incorporate this also to the Python API?

Comment: The updated link for the `IloModeler.abs` method can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloModeler.html#abs(ilog.concert.IloIntExpr)). In case it goes stale again, it can be found by navigating to CPLEX Java Reference Manual > ilog.concert > Interfaces > IloModeler > abs.

Comment: While `abs` is not available in the CPLEX Python API (a low level API), it _is_ available in [DOcplex](https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/documentation/optimization-modeling/modeling-for-python/) (a Python modeling language that lives on top of the CPLEX Python API, or that can be used to solve on the cloud). See the docplex.mp.model.abs method [here](https://cdn.rawgit.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-doc/master/docs/mp/docplex.mp.model.html?highlight=abs#docplex.mp.model.Model.abs).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the links! `DOcplex` looks quite appealing at first glance, will take a look; might indeed simplify my current problem significantly.